# GIT cannot spawn askpass No such file or directory while cloning Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I had referred many sites to solve Git repository clone in VS 2017 TFS. But unable to fix it. Please help me.

Below are Visual Studio Version Details.

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017

Version : 15.9.1

**Note**: I had connected to open network with no proxy settings in LAN.

Below are some of sites i referred.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/176703/git-cannot-spawn-askpass-no-such-file-or-directory.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html

[Git failed with a > fatal error. could not read Username for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997966/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-could-not-read-username-for)

[Visual Studio 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error)

Comment: What is your problem? Error?

Comment: After connecting to TFS manage connections, I am Not able to clone git repository of specific Project  in VS 2017 . Error: git fatal error. For more details, I had already mentioned in my question itself and related links had been mentioned in description.

Comment: Detailed Error: 


Git failed with a fatal error.

HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/professional/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://XYZ-ai.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled


Please help me. I had upgraded to VS 15.9.2 version. but still facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being tracked in a couple of places:

https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949

[Visual studio 2017 with bitbucket, terminal prompts disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757837/visual-studio-2017-with-bitbucket-terminal-prompts-disabled)

I posted the following as a comment on the SO link:

I discovered that simply grabbing the **AzureDevOps.Authentication.dll** assembly from the  [Git Credential Manager for Windows v1.18.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.18.2) zip file and dropping it into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<<<VSEdition>>>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core` folder allowed me to clone a **Dev.Azure.com** repo.

HTH.

Sam.

Comment: didn't work for me